# Cannot send content-body with GET request

Tags: .net, get, elasticsearch

I am trying to execute a simple "request body search" on Elasticsearch like the [following example](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html) but using .NET instead of curl

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
'
```

Below is my .NET code.

```
var uri = "http://localhost:9200/myindex/_search";
var json = "{ \"query\" : { \"term\" : { \"user\" : \"kimchy\" } } }";

var request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.ContentType = "text/json";
request.Method = "GET";

var responseString = string.Empty;

using (var streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();

    var response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        responseString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the following error.

```
Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.
...
Exception Details: System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.
...
Line 54: using (var streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
```

Is there any way I can send a content-body with a `GET` request using standard .NET classes. Or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the `Method` to `POST` is a workaround.

```
request.Method = "POST";
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states that a `ProtocolViolationException` will be thrown if the `GetResponseStream()` method is called with a `GET` or `HEAD` method.

Comment: I got the same issue but the Method has to be GET , I don't have permission to change it from GET to POST, is there some other workaround for this issue ?